# Remove "add to cart" button without removing Woocommerce Product Add-ons

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

I am usig WooCommerce with WooCommerce product add-ons plugin. I have seen many answers that remove the "add to cart" button on single product pages. **They also remove WooCommerce product add-ons as well.**

Can anyone provide insight how to add back "add-ons" while removing "add to cart" button?

Here is what I have to remove the "add to cart" button but removes add-ons as well:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );

function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WooCommerce product Add-Ons needs **`woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button`** action hook to display all Add-ons fields and data.

So in the code below will work for simple and variable products, just removing the add-to-cart and quantity fields, allowing product Add-ons fields and data to be displayed.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'remove_add_to_cart_buttons', 1 );
function remove_add_to_cart_buttons() {
    global $product;

    // For simple product types
    if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_before_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
    // For variable product types (keeping attribute select fields)
    elseif( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
    }
}
function custom_before_single_add_to_cart(){
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) return;

    // Simple Products
    if ( $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); // (Optional)

        echo '<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">'; // (Optiona

            ## @since 2.1.0.
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); // <== NEEDED by Add-ons

            ## @since 3.0.0.
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity' ); // Optional

            ## @since 3.0.0.
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity' ); // Optional

            ## @since 2.1.0.
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); // Optional

        echo '</form>'; // Optional

        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); // Optional
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

> As the add to cart button is removed, you will not be able to submit the Add-ons data

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for all the help!!!